# in flutter how to set wait for a future method

Tags: android, json, api, flutter, future

i have three api's ,First api is responsible to get take some data , that is used in the second api and so on the second api is responsible for some data which is necessary for the 3rd api. 
i have made 3 future functions. they are in a sequence .
for example ,

```
  int datafromapi_one;
  bool datafromapi_two;
  bool datafromapi_three;

  Future getDataFromApi_one() async {

    http.Response api_one_response = await http.get("http://api_one_url");
    int data_from_api_one = json.decode(api_one_response.body); // the response data is in numeric only

    setState(){

      datafromapi_one = data_from_api_one;

    }

  }

  Future getDataFromApi_two() async {

    http.Response api_two_response = await http.get("http://api_two_url?with_parameter=datafromapi_one");
    bool data_from_api_two = json.decode(api_two_response.body); // the response data is in boolean value

    setState(){

      datafromapi_two = data_from_api_two;

    }

  }



  Future getDataFromApi_three() async {

    http.Response api_three_response = await http.get("http://api_three_url?with_parameter=datafromapi_two");
    bool data_from_api_three = json.decode(api_three_response.body); // the response data is in boolean value

    setState(){

      datafromapi_three = data_from_api_three;

    }

  }



  FlatButton(
  onPressed:(){

  getDataFromApi_one();
  print(datafromapi_one.toString());

  getDataFromApi_two();
  print(datafromapi_two.toString());

  getDataFromApi_three();
  print(datafromapi_three.toString());

  if(datafromapi_three == true && datafromapi_two == true && datafromapi_one != null ){

  // Navigate.to.next.screen()//

  }
  else{
  // Toast.Show( error on which api )
  }
  }
  )
```

i implemented this method, and got stuck in the app that sometime the data from api_one is recieving later and the dependent api's are not working well without the data from first api.
now i want to set some wait function on api_two so that if the data is not arrived then it has to wait for the data until it arrives and then run the second api with that data , and want to put that api_three on wait until data arrives. and then run api_three. i hope you can understand and have a proper solution for me.

Comment: `await getDataFromApi_one(); print(...); await getDataFromApi_two(); print(...); await getDataFromApi_three(); print(...)`

Comment: so adding await wont release the control and the second method wont run before the _one method is successfully completed ?

Comment: yes, have you read https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await?

Comment: Thank you so much @pskink it worked. lot of love for you brother <3